# Paket Newtonsoft ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, paket

This is ASP.NET 4.5 console application.

The error that I am getting is:

> CalculateArrivalDate.cs(14,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [c:\dev\deneme\QueryData\src\Notific
>   ationPlatform.QueryData.Pnr\NotificationPlatform.QueryData.Pnr.csproj]

This is a new class that is using JSON.

The following line is from **paket.dependencies**:

```
nuget Newtonsoft.Json <= 6.0.4
```

I tried multiple versions of this line. (without version number, with other numbers as well as variations of `<` and `>` signs). None of them worked for me.

When I go to **packages\Newtonsoft.Json\lib\net45** folder with above configuration, I can see that **Newtonsoft.Json.dll** is located with version number 6.0.4.17603

When I check **src\NotificationPlatform.QueryData.Pnr\NotificationPlatform.QueryData.Pnr.csproj** file, I can see that reference is added correctly:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: I found the issue. I did 2 things:
1) I updated paket.references file of parent project
2) I manually executed "paket install"

It is all good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I did 2 things:

1) I updated paket.references file of parent project

2) I manually executed "paket install" which build all project files again.

It is all good now